# UICollectionView horizontal paging not centring after rotation

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewflowlayout, scroll-paging

I am currently working on a horizontal gallery scroll view. I have decided to use UICollectionView with horizontal paging enabled. It almost works great... expect on rotation the  collection view cells are not centred (see screenshot attached), where red is the first cell and yellow is the second one.

[image]

It usually works fine on the first rotation but then just messes up :D

This is the code I have for setting up the class:

```
class GalleryScrollView: UIView {
    private var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    private var layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout!
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupView()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        layout.invalidateLayout()
    }

    private func setupView() {
        layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.frame,
                                          collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "PhotoGalleryCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "photoGalleryCell")
        collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
        collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.autoresizingMask = .flexibleWidth
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .green
        self.addSubview(collectionView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor),
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor)
        ])

        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Followed by the collection view setup:

```
extension GalleryScrollView: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "photoGalleryCell", for: indexPath) as? PhotoGalleryCell else {
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }

    if indexPath.item == 0 {
        cell.backgroundColor = .red
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = .yellow
    }

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    2
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return self.frame.size
}
```

I tried playing around with `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {` but for some reason the func was never called.

Did anyone else run into this problem? I saw a lot of topics in objective c threads, not much in swift. I am also somewhat struggling to understand why this is happening, so just understanding the problem would be very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: How are you handling rotations?

Comment: Have you read through this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41711297/6257435

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't seem to have handled rotations. You need to `reloadData` when a rotation occurs. You'll get the event in `UIViewController` from there you can call `reloadData` on the instance of your `UICollectionView`.

```
class GalleryViewController: UIViewController {
    //...
    var galleryScrollView: GalleryScrollView
    //...
    override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.willTransition(to: newCollection, with: coordinator)
        galleryScrollView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }
    //...
}
```

Then in `GalleryScrollView`:

```
class GalleryScrollView: UIView {
    var currentVisibleIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    //....
}

extension GalleryScrollView: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    //...
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        let attributes =  collectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at: currentVisibleIndexPath)
        let newOriginForOldIndex = attributes?.frame.origin
        return newOriginForOldIndex ?? proposedContentOffset
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let center = CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x + (scrollView.frame.width / 2), y: (scrollView.frame.height / 2))
        if let indexPath = self.screenView.indexPathForItem(at: center) {
            currentVisibleIndexPath = indexPath
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't include it in here, but I tried reloading the data, initially in the ' override func layoutSubviews() ' since from my understanding this func is called on rotation, as well as from the view controller 'willTransition' func, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to have helped. Is it possible I have to calculate the offset manually? If so do you have any recommendations on how I could do this? Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: In that case, you might just have to scroll to the right index path after the layout has been validated. Check the update.

Comment: Thanks for your help!